# Intersection of ellipsoids with planes sometimes not working!

Tags: regions, geometry

I am trying to find the intersection of an ellipsoid and a plane and I am getting strange results.... Sometimes it works and some others it does not.

```
(* this RegionIntersection works *)
elip1 = Ellipsoid[{8/Sqrt[3], 8/Sqrt[3], 4/Sqrt[
3]}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
pl1 = InfinitePlane[{{-0.0577, -0.0577, 2.2516}, {2.3671, 2.3671, 
 2.3671}, {2.2516, -0.0577, -0.0577}}];
inter1 = RegionIntersection[elip1, pl1];
disInter1 = DiscretizeRegion[inter1];
elip1Gr = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], elip1}];
Show[elip1Gr, disInter1]
```

(* the following RegionIntersection does not work *)

```
elip2 = Ellipsoid[{4 Sqrt[3], 8/Sqrt[3], 
 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
inter2 = RegionIntersection[elip2, pl1];
disInter2 = DiscretizeRegion[inter2];
elip2Gr = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], elip2}];
Show[elip2Gr, disInter2]
```

When I check if the intersection is a region, I get a negative answer!!

```
DiscretizeRegion[inter2] // RegionQ
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use rational numbers in your plane, something like: `inter2 = RegionIntersection[elip2, Rationalize @ pl1]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you so much for the solution... It works wonderfully, now! However, I am still not sure why it was necessary to use rational numbers in the plane to get it to work. Any hints would be more than welcome!

Comment: @Karl_Heineker I see that you registered a profile, but this question was posted under an unregistered one.  Please consider using [the contact form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/contact) to request a profile merger.